# Export to Excel from django shell

Tags: python, django, excel, shell

I have a function that fetches data from a server and I have taken it in dictionary format. Now I want run that function in django shell and generate that file in my local drive.
Here is my program to generate excel, it has HttpResponse which I don't need so what changes do I need to make?

```
def to_excel(excelStr, filename):  

""" To Generate Excel Sheets """

response = HttpResponse(excelStr, mimetype='application/vnd.ms-excel')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s.xls' \
    % str(filename)
return response
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
with open('%s.xls' % (filename,)) as f:
    f.write(excelStr)
```